# Is the function bijective?

Tags: functions

let $B$ be the set of all binary strings over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$. Consider the function $f \colon B\to B$ such that for any string $x$, the value $f(x)$ is obtained by replacing all $0$'s in $x$ by $1$'s and all $1$'s in $x$ by $0$'s. Is the function bijective? Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bijective means the for each input has an unique output for all inputs, and the amount of outputs is equal to the amount of outputs.

$00\rightarrow11$
$01\rightarrow10$
$10\rightarrow01$
$11\rightarrow00$

The function does match this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

**Harder way**:

$f$ is bijective $\iff f$ is injective and surjective.

If $f$ is injective, we need to show $f(x) = f(y) \iff x = y$, where $x$ and $y$ are binary strings.

To show that it is surjective, we need to show that for any $y \in B$, then there exists an $x \in B$ such that $f(x) = y$.

**Easier way**:

$f$ is bijective $\iff$ it has an inverse.